# Cannot call value of non-function type '((AnyClass) -> Bool)!'

Tags: ios, swift3

here is my code.

```
    let myDeepLinkAction: UAAction = UAAction(block: {(args:UAActionArguments, handler:UAActionCompletionHandler) -> Void in
                            handler(UAActionResult.empty())
                            }, acceptingArguments: {(arguments: UAActionArguments) in

                                if arguments.situation == UASituation.backgroundPush {

                                    return true
                                }
                                return ((arguments.value! as AnyObject).isKind(of: NSString) || (arguments.value! as AnyObject).isKind(of: URL))

                        })
```

that type error is coming after swift version conversion 2.2 to 3.0,pls give me solution as possible.

Comment: try to return Bool instead of void

Comment: thanks for valuable advise.

Comment: Tell me if its working or not ?

Comment: Look in the documentation if the function `empty()` exists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the solution,its simple

```
 let myDeepLinkAction: UAAction = UAAction(block: {(args:UAActionArguments, handler:UAActionCompletionHandler) -> Void in
                        handler(UAActionResult.empty())
                        }, acceptingArguments: {(arguments: UAActionArguments) in

                            if arguments.situation == UASituation.backgroundPush {

                                return true
                            }
                            return (arguments.value! is NSString || arguments.value! is URL)

                    })
```

> return (arguments.value! is NSString || arguments.value! is URL)

Comment: swift 3 implement new syntax ,this url will be quite useful for swift 3.0 user http://www.wadecantley.com/lifeblog/2016/10/4/migrating-code-to-swift-30-xcode-8

Answer (score 0):

Make use of classForKeyedArchiver property

For eg : If you want to find out if a view controller belongs to a certain class , use the following snippet

```
if sampleController.isKind( of : listOfFlowersViewController.classForKeyedArchiver()!)
{

//your success code here

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue when I updated to swift 3 in xcode 8

```
for view in subViews {
 if ((view as AnyObject).isKind(of : UIScrollView))
 {
            scrollView = view as? UIScrollView
        }
```

It was showing error "Cannot call value of non-function type '((AnyClass) -> Bool)!"
Then I added this "classForKeyedArchiver()"
           for view in subViews {

```
               if ((view as AnyObject).isKind(of : 
        UIScrollView().classForKeyedArchiver!))

            {

                            scrollView = view as? UIScrollView
           }
```

Thanks a lot,it worked for me.